# vhosts settings in xampp linux

Tags: linux, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp, vhosts

Could somebody help me please with configuring the vhosts in XAMPP, Linuxmint.

Xampp starts correct and I see the xampp orange splash-page.. it's ok. 
I opened vhosts file in '**/opt/lampp/etc/extra**' directory and added the following code

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/public_html"
    ServerName test.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Also opened "**etc/hosts**" and added this:

```
127.0.0.2 test.dev
```

Restart XAMPP...

But the result, when I go to test.dev or 127.0.0.2 is the same orange splashpage.. so it shows the 127.0.0.1..

Also http:// localhost/phpmyadmin/

Says:

```
Access forbidden!

New XAMPP security concept:

Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Apache/2.4.2 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
```

any help will appreciate!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you check `httpd-xampp.conf` ? There shoul be a section labeled `#
# New XAMPP security concept
#`

Comment: yes, i even tried to comment it out. the message has just rephrased, the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Just uncommented the string in httpd.conf:

```
# XAMPP 
#Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```